# Adding HTML slideshow to multiple pages (without using frames)

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I am new to the site (and coding) so please bear with me!

I am trying to add the following clickable slideshow to my site in a way that means I can change the images in one file (HTML or JS) and this be reflected on every page on which the slideshow is called:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
<td width="100%">
    <img src="image1.bmp" width="200" height="200" name="photoslider"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%">
        <form method="POST" name="rotater">
            <div align="center">
                <center><p>
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
var photos=new Array()
var text=new Array()
var which=0
var what=0
photos[0]="image1.bmp"
photos[1]="image2.bmp"
photos[2]="image3.bmp"
text[0]="Image One"
text[1]="Image Two"
text[2]="Image Three"
window.onload=new Function("document.rotater.description.value=text[0]")
function backward(){
if (which>0){
window.status=''
which--
document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
what--
document.rotater.description.value=text[what];
}
}
function forward(){
if (which<photos.length-1){
which++
document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
what++
document.rotater.description.value=text[what];
}
else window.status='End of gallery'
}
function type()
{
alert("This textbox will only display default comments")
}
</script>
<p><input type="text" name="description" style="width:200px" size="50">

<p><input type="button" value="<<Back" name="B2"
  onClick="backward()"> <input type="button" value="Next>>" name="B1"
  onClick="forward()"><br />
  </p>
  </center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Currently I have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="images.js"></script>
```

in the relevant html div. to call a simple .js file which displays the images in one long list, e.g.

```
document.write('<p>Image One</p>')
document.write('<a href="image1.png"><img src="image1small.png" alt=Image One; style=border-radius:25px></a>')
document.write('<p>Image Two</p>')
document.write('<a href="image2.png"><img src="image2small.png" alt=Image Two; style=border-radius:25px></a>')
```

I have tried every way I can think of, and searched many posts on here to try and get the slideshow to display within the same div. I have copied the html code into the .js file and appended it with document.write on every line, I have tried / on every line, I have tried 'gettingdocument.getElementById', but nothing works!

The slideshow code itself is fine; if I put this directly onto each page then it works correctly, I just can't seem to 'link' to this code and have it run so anything appears.

Please provide the simplest possible solution for this, without any need to install jquery plugins, or use anything other than basic HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were alot of small bugs, i fixed them for you. you didn't put a semicolon after your javascript statements, tey aren't neccesary but it's cleaner code, you didn't exit alot of html tags

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td width="100%">
        <img src="image1.bmp" width="200" height="200" name="photoslider">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%">
        <form method="POST" name="rotater">
            <div align="center">
                <center>
                   <p>
                       <p id="description" style="width:200px" size="50"></p>
                       <p><a onClick="backward()"><img src="imageback.png" alt="back" />Back Image</a>
                       <p><a onClick="forward()"><img src="forward.png" alt="forward" />Forward Image</a>
                   </p>
                 </center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
 (function() {
    var photos=[];
    var text= [];
    var which=0;
    var what=0;

    photos[0]="image1.bmp";
    photos[1]="image2.bmp";
    photos[2]="image3.bmp";
    text[0]="Image One";
    text[1]="Image Two";
    text[2]="Image Three";

    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML  = text[0] 

    backward = function(){
        if (which>0){
            which--;
            window.status='';
            what--;
            console.log(which);
            document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
            document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = text[what];
        }
    }
    forward = function(){
        if (which < (photos.length-1)){
            which++;
            console.log(which);
            document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
            what++;
            document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = text[what];
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = 'End of gallery';
        }
    }
    function type()
    {
        alert("This textbox will only display default comments")
    }

})();
```

And last but not least i've created the fiddle to show you it's working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/45nobcmm/24/

Comment: excellent, thank you. Just to bug you further, if I wanted to style the 'back' and 'next' buttons to load as an image (held online), where would this go in the code? :)

Comment: ...and remove the border around the image description text (and maybe style this text to use same formatting as rest of my site)? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/45nobcmm/24/ Here's the updated fiddle with borders removed and place for the back and forward images @Arron

Comment: hmm it doesn't click onto next picture or click back:

Comment: <div id="right">
    <p>
    <tr>
        <img src="mia_small.png" width="320" height="240" name="slideshow">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form method="POST" name="rotater">
                   <p>
                       <p id="description" style="width:200px" size="50"></p>
                       <p>
                             <a onClick="backward()"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x40/691B50/ffffff&text=< Back" <br>
                             <a onClick="forward()"><img src="http://placehold.it/120x40/691B50/ffffff&text=Forward >"
                       </p>

Comment: you're not closing the <a> tag after the image :D add <a onClick="backward()"><img src="placehold.it/120x40/691B50/ffffff&text=<;Back" /></a> @Arron

Comment: thanks but still doesn't work :(

What should I be naming .js file and div element, based on the above code? :S

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript file that search for an element and change the innerHTML of the element to the slideshow you want to show.
For example this could be the script:

```
var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow');
slideshow.innerHTML = 'Your slideshow html';
```

and your main html page should have a slideshow div.

but you need to know that it's not the best solution, you should learn PHP or another back-end language and than you could use `include('page.html');` for example

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go. The div that I want the slideshow in is basically the right column on my three column page. It is only the slideshow that will be in this div, so I guess I can simply change this to slideshow.div? I will learn php in time, what benefits would this give me in this situation?

Comment: @Arron  if you want the slideshow to be in the right column than give the column an id and change the `getElementById()` to match the name of your id

Comment: I don't really understand? If I write this .js file, how and where do I call it in the HTML?

Comment: @Arron here is an [example](http://jsbin.com/dufedupajufa/2/edit). you should import the script at the bottom of the page but you don't must to because of the window.onload which wait the page to be load.